# How did I inadvertently change the default search engine?

Tags: firefox, search-engines

Occasionally upon entering a search term in the address bar, I discover that the default search engine has somehow changed from Google to Amazon.de (the second one in my list of search engines). I am not aware of how this happens. I cannot rule out accidentally having typed some keyboard shortcut, but I cannot reproduce that after researching shortcuts.

I know that in the address bar, I can **temporarily** search with a different search engine via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Up/Down. But as I said, the default is changed.

I know that in the dedicated **search bar**, I can switch the default search engine via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Up/Down. But I don't use the search bar.

What may be going on?

Comment: Is there some Amazon product installed on your computer? A plugin in your browser from Amazon? These are the most likely causes of this sort of thing. There also may be hotkeys or keywords in your browser to quickly search using a specific engine or site.

Comment: No Amazon products or plugins. Keywords for Amazon search, yes - both as a bookmark keyword and a search preferences keyword. But using them does not change the search engine permanently. Other hotkeys, I don't know - not any I am aware of.

Comment: Thank you for this question, I was accidentally changing the default search engine using the search bar method and this helped me realize how.